Need guidance on turning Nylon rod
I have a 22mm dia, 60mm length nylon rod. I wish to drill about 10mm hole in its center, and reduce the OD by turning it on Lathe. What is the minimum OD I can have without cracking it?

Depends on length from support (usually the chuck) and whether you support the rod via other methods as well

@Abel I don't foresee application of any extra support except the chuck. One end of the rod would remain the original dia.

please add the length of the rod to your post ... do not write in a comment

As @jsotola said, the length matters a lot here. Also are you concerned with the rod cracking while you turn it, or is it being used as something like a tube, with some pressurized liquid inside? If so, how much pressure is the liquid under?

Length mentioned now in question. My concern is cracking it while machining it, like acrylic cracks while machining if the tool feed is to fast or if the wall thickness is too thin.

If you do the hole, then support the rod with a steel (?) insert then the final thickness will be down to the cutting tool used for the OD.

I don't think there is going to be any steel insert. I am not a machinist and am yet to meet the machinist with directions of what I want done. Is inserting a steel support a regular way of doing things?

@Iskander: The "steel support" would normally be called a mandrel. Yes, if you want to cut something like a long, thin tube (especially if the walls are thin enough that it won't be rigid on its own) it's pretty common to use a mandrel.
